# Trying to upgrade to 16.04 from 15.10, but "the required dependency 'apt (>= 1.0.10.2ubuntu2)' is not installed"?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I tried `sudo apt-get update`, but got

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Any advice? Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: you have something already open like synaptic when you tried apt-get update

Comment: Right. And btw, how is your title relevant to the content of the question?

Answer (score 3):

Problem is solved by *manually downloading and updating the apt*.

Try to use

1. http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524267/apt_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb.

If it shows error while updating then run this following deb file first then the previous one.

2. http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524270/libapt-pkg4.16_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb

then run those commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you disable the security update repository (`wily-security`) by any chance?

If so enable it again and run: `apt-get update && apt-get -y install apt`.

After this you should have the newer apt version installed. Hence, you should now be able to run `do-release-upgrade` without any issues.

Comment: This answers the title - not the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

This .deb solves the problem. ;)

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/apt/1.0.10.2ubuntu2

Answer (score -2):

Try to download and install this package manually:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/254524270/libapt-pkg4.16_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
apt-get install ./libapt-pkg4.16_1.0.10.2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```